# Why npm keep asking me for license information even though it set "UNLICENSED"?

Tags: npm, licensing

I have already set the package.json with following code for my company private project.

```
{
  ...
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  ...
}
```

but npm seems not giving up asking me for the license.

```
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
```

Comment: What do you mean "asking" you?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay, I just update with the content

Comment: That's Yarn, not NPM, and I can't recreate that locally. Note the path - are you sure you're looking at the right package file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks comment from @jonrsharpe.

I found the package.json actually from different path, which is actually from `~/` path. For visual studio command, when I click the link it prompt, it actually jump to current path package.json file. That's why it confused me.